# Application.properties ignored when creating a Maven submodule

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven

After creating a Spring Initializr application, I ran it using server.port=9090 in the application.properties and it worked.
After creating a module (from IntelliJ), suddenlty without doing anything else, the application.properties is ignored and it tries to run again on the port 8080 as default.

Here is the structure:
[image]

Project common is empty. 
Just the maven structure. 
Thanks!

**LE:** Seems that it has to do with the packaging of the children module. Paste from my previous comment:
*what I have found now is that because of having pom in all the children, this strange behaviour is happening. The resources, are not taken in consideration. If I remove the packaging tag, they are taken in consideration, BUT, the maven clean install will complaing on that child, because it cannot find the .jar dependencies to the other children (because they have pom packaging) ...*

**LLE:** In the end I have found the problem, and I will leave it here, maybe someone else will run into it. 
So, my issue was that besides the parent pom.xml that had POM packaging, there were also childer with the same packaging. When I have removed all of them from the children modules, everything worked fine, including the maven-clean-install.
**In one word: POM packaging only for Parent module**

Comment: Add the directory structure

Comment: Did you add identifier of the parent POM in child module ? And do you try to add `server.port=9090` in child module application.properties file ?

Comment: Added more details.
@EdgarKhachatryan: yes, but with the same result.

Comment: In a Maven modular project it is preferred to have not sources in the root project. I mean that you should create another module for the Demo application which have the common maven module dependency in its pom. Then you can build the project from the root. This should do the tricks. I'm working with such structure and it works. Obviously the executable jar will be created inside the demo target subfolder

Comment: @RobertoCanini: thanks for your best practice. Indeed you are right.
But, what I have found now is that because of having <packaging>pom</packaging> in all the children, this strange behaviour is happening. The resources, are not taken in consideration. If I remove the packaging tag, they are taken in consideration, BUT, the maven clean install will complaing on that child, because it cannot find the .jar dependencies to the other children (because they have pom packaging) ...